# Yet another question on cross site scripting (XSS)

Tags: java, servlet-filters, xss

I have been combing the net in search of knowledge of how to go about putting together a solution to prevent XSS on our site.

I know that [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xss) has many questions and responses on the topic but there is still no real clear picture as to how to approach this.

So, here is another attempt to solicit information on this topic.

We have an older site which is built on a JSP Model 1 framework.  The site has a captive audience - that is you have to register to be provided a username/password.  The amount of data that user can actually enter is pretty limited - search criteria, bid prices and posting inventory to sell.

I have been looking at the usage of a [XSS filter](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/xssflt.htm) to apply across the site.  Some concerns have been raised as to that the source code is not provided with this solution and there are questions about how secure it is.

I have also seen where taglibs have been used along with adding logic on the server side.

The question are:

Is addressing XSS at the client side sufficient enough or does it need to be addressed both on the client and on the server?

Is a filter sufficient or should it be used in combination with JSTL tablib for the client?  Are there other filters out there besides the one that I have references - for I have not been able to locate one in my searches.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Try a more specific search: `[jsp][xss]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp+xss

Comment: Have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xss for some good info on preventing XSS

Comment: Thanks for the reference did not know there was a security site.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been looking at the usage of a XSS filter to apply across the site.

I suggest avoiding filters, at least in general. They can lead to "Ah! XSS!", "No, I was just writing an equation".

Either escape data or, if you want to allow markup, parse it and the generated DOM through a whitelist to remove unwelcome attributes, elements, URIs, etc.

> Is addressing XSS at the client side sufficient enough

No! You can't trust the client.

> or does it need to be addressed both on the client and on the server?

It shouldn't be handled client side at all.

Comment: so you are not a fan of using <c:out to escape the output on a given page?

Comment: Umm, to quote my answer "escape data". As I understand it, that is exactly what `c:out` does.

Comment: @boyd: Please note that `<c:out>` is not a filter and does also not run in client side, if that is where your confusion is coming from.